# DailyRollingFileAppender creating and writing to 2 files parallely

Tags: java, log4j

I have below configuration in logging.xml and the issue is its creating 2 in rollover and writing to both files.

For e.g. on below config, I have performance.log and performance.log.2020.06.08.log in my server and both these logs are active now.

Any insight would help

```
<appender name="PERFLOG" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="/wsapps/mpi/deployment/logs/performance.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d|%t|%x|%m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

<appender name="ASYNCPERF" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="PERFLOG" />
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check JavaDoc https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html. They recommend to use alternative Appender to use because of few know synchronisation issue or data loss.  Recommended one is : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html